# Script to sync local and remote tracking branches (prune, delete, and create)

Tags: git, branch

Do any of you git gurus have a script that will help with folks new to git manage their local and remote-tracking branches. Proponents of distributed version control may scoff at this idea, but I believe it will help ramp people up on git.

I'm looking for a script that will:

- Create a local branch for every new remote branch (with the same name)
- Prune remote-tracking branches for remote branches that no longer exist
- Delete local branches for those pruned remote branches (ask user for confirmation if local branch was ahead of remote)

We use a central git repo that all developers push/pull from/to. So, we want git to function more like SVN (but with better merging capabilities).

Bonus if you can get this to work with Git Extensions from the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented as a Git Extensions plugin. https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/1451

> This plugin allows users familiar with SVN to ramp up on Git faster. This plugin will:
>
> - fetch changes from a remote
> - create local branches for all remote branches not currently tracked
> - delete local branches tied to pruned remote branches
> - reset local branches to match remote branches
> - not affect local-only branches
>
> A confirmation is displayed for any change to the user's working directory.